# Python pyautogui converts "+" to "*" in Write function

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am facing an issue while attempting to input a string into a form field using PyAutoGUI. Although most of the code works fine, the string input gets "corrupted" in the process.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
user = "bjoern+admin"
user_pos = auth_fenster.left + 220, auth_fenster.top + 150
pyautogui.click(user_pos)
pyautogui.write(user, interval=0.05)
```

The expected output should be "bjoern+admin" in the input field. However, the actual output that appears in the window input field is "bjoern*admin". [API Link](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html)

I would appreciate it if someone could help me understand what I might be missing or doing wrong in my code. Why is the asterisk (*) being inserted instead of the plus (+)?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

EDIT: So the reasons seems to be that my keyboard Layout is QWERTZ, if I change it to QWERTY it works as intended. But this is no real solution to me. Open for ideas at this point.

EDIT2:

So i found this workaround

```
import pyautogui
import pyperclip

def _workaround_write(text):
    """
    This is a work-around for the bug in pyautogui.write() with non-QWERTY keyboards
    It copies the text to clipboard and pastes it, instead of typing it.
    """
    pyperclip.copy(text)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
    pyperclip.copy('')

# Test
text_with_special_chars = '@/:;\\.ABCabc?!~^[]{}()'
pyautogui.write(text_with_special_chars) 
# >>> //;\.ABCabc?§¨[]5°      -> NOK

_workaround_write(text_with_special_chars) 
# >>> @/:;\.ABCabc?!~^[]{}()       -> OK :)
```

Which works for me. Credits to [setvisible](https://github.com/setvisible) in this [Post](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/249)

Comment: how do you expect that output if user string is "bjoern.admin"?

Comment: sorry, typo in the question of course want to insert "bjoern+admin".

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is that the plus sign (+) is a special character in PyAutoGUI. It is used to represent keyboard shortcuts or key combinations. When you use pyautogui.write() method with the string "bjoern+admin", PyAutoGUI interprets the plus sign as part of a keyboard shortcut instead of treating it as a regular character.

To fix this issue, you can escape the plus sign by adding a backslash () before it. This will tell PyAutoGUI to treat the plus sign as a regular character. Here's the updated code snippet:

```
user = "bjoern\+admin"
user_pos = auth_fenster.left + 220, auth_fenster.top + 150
pyautogui.click(user_pos)
pyautogui.write(user, interval=0.05)
```

By escaping the plus sign, PyAutoGUI will now input "bjoern+admin" as expected. Give it a try and let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only leads to the result that I now get `"bjoern\*admin"`

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact that I use a qwertz keyboard layout because I am German. No a qwerty layout.

Comment: Confirmed, if I change my layout it works as intended without escaping. Now it question is how to make it work for me.

Comment: To overcome this issue, you can use a workaround that involves copying the text to the clipboard and pasting it.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, David Suzuki!

Several of your answers appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Found this workaround which worked for this special problem.

````
import pyautogui
import pyperclip

def _workaround_write(text):
    """
    This is a work-around for the bug in pyautogui.write() with non-QWERTY keyboards
    It copies the text to clipboard and pastes it, instead of typing it.
    """
    pyperclip.copy(text)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
    pyperclip.copy('')

# Test
text_with_special_chars = '@/:;\\.ABCabc?!~^[]{}()'
pyautogui.write(text_with_special_chars) 
# >>> //;\.ABCabc?§¨[]5°      -> NOK

_workaround_write(text_with_special_chars) 
# >>> @/:;\.ABCabc?!~^[]{}()       -> OK :)```
````